# How to allow Google App Maker app access with no sign-in required

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have created an App in Google AppMaker and have shared the Deployment to Anyone with the link can view (No sign-in required).

Application Access in Deployment Settings is set to "Do not restrict access to this application".
Application is set to runs with Developer Account.

However, if someone try to access the app with the..

..Deployment URL (https://script.google.com/macros/.../exec), they get redirected to login screen (https://accounts.google.com/signin/...),
the app does open correctly after signing in, but the sign-in shouldn't be required.

..Link to share (https://drive.google.com/file/.../view), they get: No preview available

I switched once to "Application set to runs with User Account", but results remains same. Actually, I reset this setting as I consider "Application set to runs with User Account" to require User authentication in order to load their assigned permission.

I most probably missed something on the way of sharing my app.
Can someone please help?

Let me know if you require more details about this case.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

> [Note: App Maker apps are only available to users in your G Suite domain. You can't share them with external users.](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment)

To make sure only users on your domain can access it, users need to sign-in.